# How to delete all empty line strings when clicking on button

Tags: javascript

I need to delete all empty lines, if input is empty and i will click button the empty line will appear on page, how do i delete them or replace?

Here is my code

```
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelector('#list');
var del = document.querySelector(".delete");
var arr = [];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var valInp = inp.value;
  arr.push(valInp);
  inp.value = "";

  list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();

});
```

Comment: trim your data. and check if it is empty then do not do anything. Use `trim()` of javascript

Comment: Just don't do anything in your click listener (e.g. return immediately?) if the input is empty?

Comment: what kind of element is having `id` as `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't add it if it's empty, as stated by @Thernys

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var valInp = inp.value;

  if (valInp === '')
    return;

  arr.push(valInp);
  inp.value = "";

  list.innerHTML = arr.join("<br>").trim();
});
```